# Разница  между override и virtual

Tags: c#, ооп

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Документацию долго перечитывал, а в сети только сравнения `new` и `override`.

Comment: а вы не пробовали учиться не по г**носайтам, а по книгам? Очень, знаете ли, от таких трудностей помогает

Comment: Если msdn.microsoft.com это г**носайт, то Вам трудно угодить.

Comment: Ну тогда вы как минимум не очень объективны - в msdn, конечно, нет (или скорее всего нет) статьи, где говорилось бы об отличиях override и virtual (но это вполне логично). Однако же из статей о каждом из этихслов очень даже  можно увидеть разницу.
И да, вы таки не поверите, но msdn - это плохая замена учебнику (но не плохой сайт)

Comment: Согласен с вами. Просто сравнивал оттуда 2 определения и было такое чувство, что описывается один и тот же инструмент.

Comment: Переходи на Java там все методы виртуальны, а @Override всего лишь аннотация для компилятора :). Хорошее должно быть простым. Если сложно - это первый признак кривизны.

Comment: @Barmaley

Авторы `C#` просто придерживаются другой школы, и сложно упрекнуть их в неправильно принятых решениях (вопросы производительности можно выкинуть за скобки):

> **[Anders Hejlsberg]** When we make something `virtual` in a platform, we're making an awful lot of promises about how it evolves in the future.  For a non-`virtual` method, we promise that when you call this method, `x` and `y` will happen.  When we publish a `virtual` method in an API, we not only promise that when you call this method, `x` and `y` will happen [`(...)`](http://goo.gl/VxGMD)

Comment: Я только пришел с Java) 
Многие концепции послее нее в C# легко даются, но C# более гибкий, как мне показалось.

Comment: @alex91 Хороший пример провоцирующего, но не несущего никакой существенной информации комментария `:)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*override* - модификатор для переопределения виртуальных методов (virtual), свойств и событий базового класса.

*virtual* - ключевое слово, применяемое к методам, свойствам и событиям, которые могут быть переопределены (override) в производных классах.

Answer (score 6):

Ключевое слово `virtual` используется для изменения объявлений методов, свойств, индексаторов и событий и разрешения их переопределения в производном классе.
Модификатор `override` требуется для расширения или изменения абстрактной или виртуальной реализации унаследованного метода, свойства, индексатора или события. 
Подробнее можно почитать об этом [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6tcf2h8w.aspx).